# xcode image position x y update realtime

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, real-time

I am trying to move an imageView according to coordinates I get in realtime from the server. The movement of the image is lagging, if I use a CGPath instead of an imageView it is very smooth so the issue is not from the server.

Is there a better efficient way to move an imageView by updating its X and Y continuously.

I am using the code below to update the imageView coordinates.

```
imgView.frame=CGRectMake(x-70/2, y-70/2, 70, 70);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UIView's animation APIs:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     imgView.frame = CGRectMake(x-70/2, y-70/2, 70, 70);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```